# Can't map fields in DECS activity creation

Tags: oracle, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I can't map fields in My Domino Enterprise Connection Services (DECS) activity creation. Selecting fields has no effect.

I am using Domino Server 9.0.1 x64 on a Windows Server 2008. My DECS activity is using a connection to Oracle Inventory EBS server in UNIX with an Oracle 12c client installed on my windows server machine. The Oracle server is accessible from the windows server machine.

[image: Keymap error illustration]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of selecting the fields with a mouse click, I had to write them down manually in the bottom input.